# Illegal unit of measure used (pt inserted) inTexStudio

Tags: graphics, errors

I am a new TexStudio user. I am trying to insert images into my file and am obtaining the following error:

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...twidth=688,natheight=706]{"figure 2.png"}
```

This is the code I used to insert the figure:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8,natwidth=688,natheight=706]{"figure 2.png"}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \caption{ROC Curve of Model Including Sex, Race, Gallstone Size and Bodyweight as Predictors of Gallstone Dissolution}
    \end{flushleft}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
```

The same error was obtained when I run the code with and without the image dimensions.

Comment: width takes a _length_ not a number, also (assuming you are using pdftex) do not specify natheight and natwidth

Comment: unrelated but `\label` needs to be in the same environment as `\caption`

Comment: And the texstudio tag does not make sense here, as this is a latex issue, not an editor issue. Welcome, btw

Comment: And using flushleft on the caption does not really make sense, what are you trying?